# Mongo Zone Sharding Implementation Issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

As I am new with MongoDB.

I have configured 1 config server, 2 shards and all are connected with mongod client. Also, Mongos is UP and Running.

I am currenctly implementing Sharding using Mongo Zone. As I have to store the data accourding to country/Zone. But facing below error in shards:

```
2018-05-03T16:22:40.200+0530 W SHARDING [conn13] Chunk move failed :: caused by :: 
      NoShardingEnabled: Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr
2018-05-03T16:27:11.223+0530 I SHARDING [Balancer] Balancer move testdb.user: 
      [{ zipcode: "380001" }, { zipcode: "39000" }), from rs1, to rs0 failed :: caused by :: 
      NoShardingEnabled: Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr
```

I have already started server with `--shardsvr` and also mentioned in config file as well. But still I am facing issue.

Please help me get this resolve.

Thanks in Advance.

Ankit

Comment: Hi Ankit Jani, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is actually outside the scope of this site, because it's more about database administration than about programming. I recommend you ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead; sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Thanks @VinceBowdren, my bad as I was in a hurry so I forgot to check for the site. Thanks again I will move this question to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).